# Differentiation, how do I find the turning points of this curve? also how do I determine whether the turning point is a maximum or a minimum?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Given $$y=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$
> what are the coordinates of the turning point?

I believe that when you differentiate it you get $x=e$, but I need help finding both coordinates.

How do I determine whether the turning point is a maximum or a minimum?

Another part of the question is : The points A and B lie on the curve and have x-coordinates 2 and 4. show that the line AB is parallel to the x axis.

how do I go about this

Comment: $y'=\frac{1-\ln{x}}{x^2}$

Comment: $y'=(1-\ln x)/x^2$

Comment: also another part of the question is : The points A and B lie on the curve and have x-coordinates 2 and 4. show that the line AB is parallel to the x axis

Comment: can anyone help with this last part? I'm not sure where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating $y = \frac{\ln x}{x}$ gives you $$y' = \frac{1 - \ln x}{x^2}$$ which, as you seem to have determined, is zero when $x = e$.  To get the $y$-coordinate we just need to plug $x = e$ back into the original function, so the $y$-coordinate is $\frac{\ln e}{e} = \frac{1}{e}$.  That tells us that the turning point is at $(e,1/e)$. To determine whether this is a maximum or minimum, we notice that because $x^2$ is always non-negative, the sign of $y'$ is determined by the sign of $1 - \ln x$.  Now, if $x < e$ then $1 - \ln x > 0$ and if $x > e$ then $1 - \ln x < 0$.  This tells us that $y$ is increasing on $(0,e)$ and decreasing on $(e,\infty)$, and so $(e,1/e)$ is a maximum.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply, my confusion only lies now in the fact that the question for determining the maximum or minimum is worth 5 marks. is there an other way to express this?

Comment: The other way would be the sign of $y''(e)=-\dfrac 3{\mathrm{e}}$: as it is negative, we have a maximum.

Comment: also another part of the question is : The points A and B lie on the curve and have x-coordinates 2 and 4. show that the line AB is parallel to the x axis.

Comment: can anyone help with this? I'm not sure where to start?